# GROUP_CONCAT With Nested Set Model

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, nested, group-concat

I have an application that uses a nested set model class to organise my data, however I'm trying to write a query that will group_concat my results. I know I need to put some sub select statements somewhere but I can't figure it out!

Here's my structure at the moment:

table: person

```
 -----------+------------+-----------
|Person_ID  | Name       | Age       |
 -----------+------------+-----------
| 1         | Mark Vance | 19        |
| 2         | Michael Tsu| 22        |
| 3         | Mark Jones | 29        |
| 4         | Sara Young | 25        |
 -----------+------------+-----------
```

table: person_to_group

```
 ----+------------+-----------
|ID  | Person_ID  | Group_ID  |
 ----+------------+-----------
| 1  | 3          | 1         |
| 2  | 3          | 2         |
| 3  | 1          | 2         |
| 4  | 4          | 3         |
 ----+------------+-----------
```

table: groups

```
 ----------+--------------+--------------+-------------
|Group_ID  | Group_Name   | Group_Left   | Group_Right |
 ----------+--------------+--------------+-------------
| 1        | Root         | 1            | 6           |
| 2        | Node         | 2            | 5           |
| 3        | Sub Node     | 3            | 4           |
 ----------+--------------+--------------+-------------
```

I need to render something like this with my results:

//Grab the group_IDs for this person and put them in the class tag...

```
<li class="2 3">Sara Young is in the Sub Node Group</li>
```

Notice that although Sara is in the Sub Node group, she is still being given the id for Node aswell because she is a child of Node.

The following is the query that I am working with as a starting point.

```
SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT( CAST( gg.Group_ID AS CHAR ) SEPARATOR ' ' ) Group_IDs
        FROM groups gg
        LEFT JOIN person_to_group AS t1 ON gg.Group_ID = t1.Group_ID
        LEFT JOIN person AS t2 ON t2.Person_ID = t1.Person_ID
        GROUP BY t2.per_ID 
        ORDER BY t2.Name ASC
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd write the query:

```
SELECT p.Name, 
  GROUP_CONCAT( g.Group_Name ) AS Group_List,
  GROUP_CONCAT( CAST( gg.Group_ID AS CHAR ) SEPARATOR ' ' ) AS Group_ID_List
FROM person AS p
INNER JOIN person_to_group AS pg ON p.Person_ID = pg.Person_ID
INNER JOIN groups AS g ON pg.Group_ID = g.Group_ID
INNER JOIN groups AS gg ON g.Group_Left BETWEEN gg.Group_Left AND gg.Group_Right
GROUP BY p.Name
ORDER BY p.Name ASC
```

Note that if you group by person name, you also need to GROUP_CONCAT the list of group names. According to your schema, a person could belong to multiple groups, because of the many-to-many relationship.

I also recommend against using `SELECT *` in general.  Just specify the columns you need.

Answer (score 0):

This was little bit interesting as I do programming in both MsSQL and MySql. In SQL I have used function called STUFF. In MySQL you can use a function called INSERT. I tried out the below query in MsSQL. Don't have a MySQL handy to try out my query. If I have time I will post the MySQL version of the query.

```
DECLARE @person TABLE (Person_ID INT, Name VARCHAR(50), Age INT)
INSERT INTO @person VALUES
(1,'Mark Vance',19),
(2,'Michael Tsu',22),
(3,'Mark Jones',29),
(4,'Sara Young',25)


DECLARE @groups TABLE (Group_ID INT, Group_Name VARCHAR(50), Group_Left INT, Group_Right INT)
INSERT INTO @groups VALUES
(1,'Root',1,6),
(2,'Node',2,5),
(3,'Sub Node',3,4)

DECLARE @person_to_group TABLE (ID INT, Person_ID INT, Group_ID INT)
INSERT INTO @person_to_group VALUES
(1,3,1),
(2,3,2),
(3,1,1),
(4,4,1),
(4,1,1)

SELECT *,STUFF((SELECT ',' + CAST(g.Group_ID AS VARCHAR) FROM @groups g 
    JOIN @person_to_group pg ON g.Group_ID = pg.Group_ID AND pg.Person_ID = a.Person_ID FOR XML PATH('')) , 1, 1, '' ) FROM @person a
```

**Function**: INSERT(str,pos,len,newstr)
**Documentation**: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_insert